# Prove: $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod {n},n=2701$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod {n},n=2701$

$n=2701=37\cdot 73$

By Fermat's little theorem:
$$2^{37-1}\equiv 1\pmod {37}$$
$$2^{73-1}\equiv 1\pmod {73}$$

How to combine these relations to get the statement?

Comment: @Alessio Ranallo  CRT solves the system of congruences, but here I think some of  congruence relation properties must be used.

Comment: Since $2700 \equiv 36 \pmod{72}$, Fermat's little theorem doesn't suffice. You need to show that $2^{36} \equiv 1 \pmod{73}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

- $2^{9}\equiv+1\pmod{73}\implies2^{2700}\equiv(2^{9})^{300}\equiv(+1)^{300}\equiv1\pmod{73}$
- $2^{18}\equiv-1\pmod{37}\implies2^{2700}\equiv(2^{18})^{150}\equiv(-1)^{150}\equiv1\pmod{37}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the *fast exponentiation algorithm* modulo 73:

$$\begin{array}{rlclr}
n&a&&P& \\
\hline
36&a&2&1&1\\18&a^2&4&1&1\\
9&a^4&16&a^4&16\\
4&a^8&257\equiv 37&a^4&16\\
2&a^{16}&37^2\equiv 55&a^4&16\\1&a^{32}&55^2\equiv32&a^{36}&16\cdot32\equiv\color{red}{1}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Thus $2^{36}\equiv 1\mod 37$ and $\mod73$, and by the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z/37\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/73\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z /2701\mathbf Z, $$
$2$ has order $36$ modulo $2701$, so that $\;2^{2700}\equiv2^{2700\bmod 36}\equiv 2^0=1\mod 2701.$